# Need to be able to click on a upc code in one excel workbook and have it take me to the same upc code in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to click on a upc code in one workbook and have it take me to that same upc code in another workbook. This is the code I am using but there is some error in the code if you try to run it through Excel. If anyone knows how to figure this out your help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Found As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Found = Workbooks("SecondWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=Target.Value, _
        After:=Workbooks(“SecondWorkbook.xlsx”).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Cancel = False
        Workbooks("SecondWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Found.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `“SecondWorkbook.xlsx”` to `"SecondWorkbook.xlsx"`

   Double-quotation marks (i.e. `"`) are used in VBA to signify the start and end of string literals, but smart-quotes (i.e. `“` and `”`) are treated in the same way as any other character and can form part of a variable name, so a statement such as `x”s = 5` is perfectly valid and sets the variable `x”s` to 5.

   Your `“SecondWorkbook.xlsx”` was therefore being treated as an attempt to use the `xlsx”` property of a non-existent `“SecondWorkbook` object.
2. Change

   ```
   Workbooks("SecondWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Found.Select
   ```

   to

   ```
   Workbooks("SecondWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
   Workbooks("SecondWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Activate
   Found.Select
   ```

   because you can't `Select` a cell on a worksheet that is not active.

Comment: @ttools You could always accept this answer to "Thank him". This also helps let others know you do not need any more assistance.